# SSRS invalid relational operator

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, plsql, error-handling

I am facing an error while incorporating an Oracle query in a SSRS report.

The below mentioned query is supposed to give output from a table TABLE1 on the basis of values selected for twofilters for VAR1 and VAR2. VAR1 must be selected by the user. VAR2(i.e. a date field) by default will show all the results. VAR2 will show results for a particular date if that is selected by the user.

Plesae note that this query runs just fine in Oracle. However, when I execute this code in SSRS, it throws the below mentioned error: "**ORA-00920: invalid relational operator**"

Would really appreciate any help here.

```
Select Distinct 
           VAR1,
           VAR2,
           AMT_FIELD
   From TABLE1 SPF 
  Where VAR1 = (:prm1) 
    And (CASE 
             WHEN ((:PRM2) IS NOT NULL AND VAR2 = (:PRM2)) THEN  1
             WHEN ((:PRM2) IS NULL AND VAR2 >= (SELECT min(VAR2) FROM TABLE1 NI Where NI.VAR1 = (:prm1))) THEN 1
             ELSE 0                                  
         END) = 1 ;
```

Thanks

Comment: Replace your `:` symbols with the `@` symbol for your parameters. Granted that those are the parameters from the SSRS report.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, removing the semicolon at the end did the trick! Thanks anyway :)